# Android ListView Edge Fading works on a 2.2 virtual device but not on Samsung 2.2.1

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, fading

On my ListActivity I get the fading edges effect when running on an Android 2.2 virtual device. However, when I use a Samsung GIO with Android 2.2.1 to run the exact same application, I get no ListView edge fading. What could be the reason? Below is the XML for my ListView in the ListActivity:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/@android:list"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="3mm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/showMixHeader"/>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I enable fading for the listview programmatically I see the fading on my Samsung Galaxy Tab:

```
listView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true); // Make sure that fading is displayed on samsung devices
```

Maybe Samsung disabled it by default on there version of Android.
(Tested on Firmware version 2.2, Samsung Galaxy Tab 7)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem with my Samsung Galaxy S (2.2.1). You're not alone ;-)

I actually never found the explanation for that. You seem to be the only one complaining on the net about that. I think it's Samsungs way of realizing their stock ROM. It's just said that they just disable a basic android feature...